# Django multiple databases: choose db where syncdb creates tables

Tags: django

My code has access to 3 databases. syncdb must create all of the model tables in two of the databases. I am unsure how to do this. The below does not work.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {}, # empty. default is required
    'db_1': { # want tables created in this
       ...
    },
    'db_2': { # want tables created in this
       ...
    },
    'other': { # do NOT want tables created in this
       ...
    },   
}
```

router: (a separate router handles auth tables)

```
import random
class OtherRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return random.choice(['db_1', 'db_2'])

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return "db_1"

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return True

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        db_list = ('db_1', 'db_2')
        if db in db_list:
            return True
        return None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. Syncdb has to be run with the db parameter. Also, maybe (not sure it matters) allow_syncdb should return False, not None, in other cases.

```
syncdb --database='db_1'
syncdb --database='db_1'
```